# Reduce a matrix with Gauss and coefficient.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have this augmented (edited after suggestion) matrix:

$$\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
α & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & α & -1 & 2 \\
α+1 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

I have to determine the values of α for which it admits solutions.

I figured out I should use Gaussian elimination, but after a certain point I can't find a way to end up with an upper triangular matrix. For example I started subtracting the first row to the third one, then the second to the third to obtain the first zero. But then?

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: So that it admits solutions to what? You haven't written a system of equations. Or is it the augmented matrix (the last column being the RHS of the equation)?

Comment: Yes, excuse me @Jean-Claude Arbaut, I didn't explain it well. It's an augmented matrix, you're right.

Comment: The system has a unique solution iff the determinant is nonzero. The determinant can be computed by the [rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus).

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to find out which values of α admit infinite solutions?

Comment: The determinant is a polynomial in $\alpha$ of degree $2$. Here it has two integer roots. For each, you have to check that the RHS is not in the span of the columns, i.e. the system has no solution. For instance, you may solve two of the equations with the third unknown as a parameter, plug into the other equation and check that it can't hold.

Comment: Hi @Moo, I am trying to solve it right now :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The rank of a matrix is the largest $r$ for which there exists an $r \times r$ submatrix with non-zero determinant. The rank of the augmented matrix of a system of linear equations is either the same as the rank of the coefficient matrix, in which case the system is consistent, or 1 more than the rank of the coefficient matrix, in which case the system is inconsistent.In your coefficient matrix, there is no $\alpha$ for which all the $2 \times 2$ determinants are 0, so the rank is either 2 or 3. Find the determinant of the coefficient matrix as a ploynomial in $\alpha$. The roots of that polynomial give the values of $\alpha$ for which the rank is 2-otherwise the rank is 3.  For each  of these roots, find the determinant of the $3 \times 3$ matrix obtained by replacing one of the columns of the coefficient matrix by the extra column of the augmented matrix, i.e. by the right-hand side of the system of equations. If at least one of these determinants is non-zero, the rank of the augmented matrix is 3 and the system is inconsistent.Otherwise,  the  coefficient and augmented augmented matrices have the same rank and the system is consistent.